# Migrate email server with MX records

Tags: email, mx-record

We need to migrate a mail server to another host with almost no downtime.

My question is, if we set two MX records one to the old server and the other to the new one like:

mail.xy 10 x.x.x.x
mail.xy 20 y.y.y.y
After all users have been created on the new server can we just turn off the old server and the emails will be delivered to the new one?

Answer (score 3):

If migrating a mail server the first thing you should do ASAP is to set your MX records to a low TTL so they will not be cached for very long.  A value of 60-300 seconds is probably low enough most of the time. Given how most sending mail servers will typically retry many times when sending email, this is probably all you need. Just set a low TTL and swap the records when you are ready.

As for your question about multiple Mail Exchange records. If you configure two MX servers one pointing at your old, and other pointing at your new any machine sending should try to send to the lowest first, and if the lowest is unreachable the next highest should be tried.

So having two records should be fine. You would probably want your new server to be the higher value.  You might also want to configure a smtp rule/route  on the old server as soon as the new server is ready to forward all incoming mail to the new server.

Comment: I'd appreciate that you put your preference too. Swap one record or use two? When I dealt with the same task I did lower TTL at the beginning of the week and then did the swap the Thursday night. After the record swap I stopped postfix on the old one and started sending from big providers test emails. Delivered promptly/within five minutes, and replies tested too. I think the 1st method is better, but 2nd slightly easier to revert. The main concern about the whole task should be new server's IPs reputation, it will be sneaky and pop up some days after the successful migration.

Comment: I have done both, I don't really have a strong preference.